# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I've a table

1.

```
CREATE TABLE `Parent` (
`ID` bigint(19) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

2.

```
CREATE TABLE `Child_1` (
`ParentID` bigint(19) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`ID` bigint(19) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`ParentID`,`ID`),
KEY `Child_1_FK1_IDX` (`ParentID`,`ID`),
CONSTRAINT `Child_1_FK1` FOREIGN KEY (`ParentID`, `ID`) REFERENCES `Child_2` (`ParentID`,   `ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

3.

```
CREATE TABLE `Child_2` (
`ParentID` bigint(19) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`ID` bigint(19) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`ParentID`,`ID`),
KEY `Child_2_FK1_IDX` (`ParentID`),
CONSTRAINT `Child_2_FK1` FOREIGN KEY (`ParentID`) REFERENCES `Parent` (`ParentID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Unfortunately, I've deleted the second table constraint.

```
CONSTRAINT `Child_1_FK1` FOREIGN KEY (`ParentID`, `ID`) REFERENCES `Child_2` (`ParentID`,   `ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

How can i recover that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to take a dump. Cold start the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Not tested):

```
ALTER TABLE Child_1
ADD FOREIGN KEY (`ParentID`, `ID`) 
REFERENCES `Child_2` (`ParentID`,   `ID`) 
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

**Update:**

To get the records violating the constraint, run this:

```
select child1.ID from 
   Child_1 child1 left join Child_2 child2 on child1.ParentID=child2.ParentID and  child1.ID=child2.ID
where child2.ID is null and child2.ParentID is null;
```

Comment: When i tested this query, i got "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails"

Comment: That means, data was already inserted into the table that is violating the constraint ... please delete such record(s) and then run this to add the constraint to the table

Comment: at what stage are you facing the problem ?